# Not able to get line breaks using redcarpet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, redcarpet

I am not able to get a line break <br>, even if  there is a line with spaces and newline in the content. Is there any way this can enabled in redcarpet.

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p

"When you do want to insert a 
 break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return."

Why is redcarpet not detecting the empty space line ?

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> rendere = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(:hard_wrap => true)
=> #<Redcarpet::Render::HTML:0xa2cc414>
irb(main):002:0> markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(rendere, :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true)
=> #<Redcarpet::Markdown:0x98ab0c0>
irb(main):003:0> markdown.render("hi how are you doing\n      \nFirst line in the next paragraph\n            \nFirst line in the third paragraph\n")
=> "<p>hi how are you doing</p>\n\n<p>First line in the next paragraph</p>\n\n<p>First line in the third paragraph</p>\n"
irb(main):004:0> markdown.render("hi how are you doing\r\n      \r\nFirst line in the next paragraph\r\n            \r\nFirst line in the third paragraph\r\n")
=> "<p>hi how are you doing</p>\n\n<p>First line in the next paragraph</p>\n\n<p>First line in the third paragraph</p>\n"
irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<br>` elements are not added if the line is the last in a paragraph – only if there is something on the next line. For example this markdown (where all the lines have two trailing spaces):

```
Has trailing spaces, but no br.  

Several lines, all with trailing spaces.  
All but the last have br elements at the end.  
This line has spaces, but no br.
```

produces this HTML with Redcarpet:

```html
<p>Has trailing spaces, but no br.  </p>

<p>Several lines, all with trailing spaces.<br>
All but the last have br elements at the end.<br>
This line has spaces, but no br.  </p>
```

Your example consists of three single line paragraphs, so each line is the last in the paragraph and doesn’t have the `<br>` added.

This behaviour is the same as the original Markdown.pl (basically – the output isn’t identical but `<br>`s are added to the same lines).